# installation of a set-up file does not work on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I would like to play Football Manager 13 on Ubuntu but the setup file does not work. But I can install that game on Windows-7 without any problem. I could not solve why it does not work on linux!

How I can install the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Football Manager 13](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14640) can be installed successfully using Wine. In fact, Football Manager 13 received a Gold rating in the WineHQ Applications Database. Additional comments about how to install Football Manager in Ubuntu can be found at [WineHQ - Football Manager 2013](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26971).

Comment: Thank you!!! I have been trying to install 2 days already.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not windows 7. A program that is designed for windows 7 may not work with ubuntu. You could try getting the program wine from the software centre, then right-clicking the setup file for football manager and opening it with wine. Wine is a program that allows you to run programs designed for windows on linux and other unixes.